# angularjs child controller has no access to parent

Tags: angularjs

I have Two nested controllers:

```
BuildingsShowCtrl = ($scope, $location, $routeParams, Building) ->
  $scope.building = Building.get
    id: $routeParams.id

AddressesChildCtrl = ($scope, $routeParams, Address) ->
  $scope.addresses = Address.query({building_id: $scope.building.id})
```

They are used this way in my nested views:

```
<div ng-controller="BuildingsShowCtrl">
  <h1>Building</h1>

  <p>
    <b>Name</b><br>
    {{building.name}}
  </p>

  <p>
    <b>Number</b><br>
    {{building.number}}
  </p>
  <div ng-include="'/assets/addresses/index.html'"></div>
</div>
```

When I hit refresh on the browser, it works fine but when I click a building from a building lists page, it fails because $scope.building is undefined in AddressesChildCtrl.

Why doesn't the child controller have access to the parent controller's scope in this case?

The app is visible here: http://lgi.herokuapp.com/buildings/

Thx!

Comment: Can you create a plunker snippet to check? From source you've posted in question there I can't see where do you use ```AddressesChildCtrl```

Comment: I think you need to use `$scope.$parent.building` - can you try with this and check?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `ngResource`, `Building.get` will return an empty object immediately and will asynchronously fill in the object data after the HTTP request is complete ([documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.%24resource#Returns)).  You can do something like this to load the address data when the object is filled in:

```
AddressesChildCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams, Address) {
  $scope.$watch('building.id', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      $scope.addresses = Address.query({building_id: $scope.building.id})
    } else {
      $scope.addresses = []
    }
  }, true);
}
```

Comment: Excellent, It works! You made my day! Is the $watch needed because otherwise, the query is executed on Address BEFORE a response has been received from Buildings? Thx!

Comment: The watch is just detecting a change in the building id.  So undefined => 1, or 1 => 2.  If you wanted to wait for the building to load, you would need to use promises, which are not available on the stock `ngResource` in the 1.0.x builds of AngularJS.  You could also pass a callback to `Building.get`, but the way your controllers are split up that could be odd.

Comment: Last question: does that mean that if I used $routeParams.id, which is the same as the building_id, It would load faster?

Comment: That would allow you to query the address immediately after the route change, even if the building is still loading.