# Data save from Child window (new window) using Parent window resources in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

I have a page (P1) and their is 1 button on P1, now I have to open another page in separate window/tab (C1). Now on C1 I have to perform Datasave on button click using the controller and module of P1. 
Is there any way so that we can save data from child window using the resources of parent window?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery Dialog box and pass any parameter you want from controller to Modal directive. As the variable is already available in controller, you dont need to pass the data back. Like below -

data ="data"

where `$scope.data` is available in directive

This guy has a written a nice article on this - http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2806-creating-a-simple-modal-system-in-angularjs.htm

Here is a fiddle too http://jsfiddle.net/theparabolink/dnCHA/

Comment: Thanks. Yes, Through model window we can achieve this. But our requirement is to open altogether a new window. I am unable to access scope and controller of my parent module, so datasave from child window using controller of parent is what I am looking for.

Comment: can you please create a plunker ? It will be easier to see the problem. In your case I think $watch will be helpful. Look at this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16958816/angularjs-child-controller-has-no-access-to-parent?rq=1